# Executable links correctly but fails to load a library

Tags: cmake, clion, pkg-config

I have Boost and Served REST API package installed in `/opt/local`.

Here's the "meaningful" part of my `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SERVED_PKG REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET served)

add_executable( rest_server rest_server.cpp )
target_link_libraries(rest_server PUBLIC PkgConfig::SERVED_PKG)
```

It does create an executable, and links it with the needed library.

However, it somehow fails to include the path to that library:

```
$ otool -L cmake-build-debug/rest_server 
cmake-build-debug/rest_server:
    libserved.1.4.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 902.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
```

Which, when I try to run it via the CLion IDE, results in a failure to load the `libserved.1.4.dylib` library:

```
/Users/ur20980/src/security2/cmake-build-debug/rest_server
dyld: Library not loaded: libserved.1.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ur20980/src/security2/cmake-build-debug/rest_server
  Reason: image not found

Process finished with exit code 6
```

When I invoke the executable manually from the terminal, it seems to be OK:

```
$ cmake-build-debug/rest_server 
Hello, World!
```

What is wrong???

Comment: Searching for libraries at runtime is determined by RPATH settings. I would suggest to read that wiki: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. Among other things it states, that with *default* settings CMake always sets full RPATH for the linked libraries, so running the executable from the build tree should succeed. It seems you have non-default settings of RPATH...

Comment: The problem is - my `CMakeLists.txt` is pretty much as you see above. Checking the CMake installation (Macports on MacOS) I only see that `MACOSX_RPATH` seems to be enabled. I do not know what variable to set to what value, to ensure that RPATH is set correctly for every executable - this project currently has only one executable, but expected to have three, two of which require different libraries that reside in a different directory...